# Automating minipage positioning

Tags: positioning, longtable, minipage

Many times we have to use tables that do not accept `footnote`. This mostly happens with `longtable` environment.

What I do for footnotes for these longtables is to actually use `minipage`, applying the trial and error method to position it well.

I use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}                     
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl,siunitx}               
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}     
\usepackage{threeparttablex}              
\usepackage{longtable}                    
\usepackage{lscape}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \caption{smth.}
    {\footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{@{} |>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}lrrrrr|rrrrr @{}}
    \toprule
          & \multicolumn{5}{c}{a}  & \multicolumn{5}{c}{b} \\
    \midrule
    dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd & dsdsd\\ \midrule
a &       &       &       &       &       & 5     &       & \cellcolor{blue!25}1     &       &  \\
b  & 4     &       &       & 4     & 5     &       &       &       &       &  \\
ab &       &       & \cellcolor{blue!25}2     &       & 4     &       & \cellcolor{blue!25}2     &       &       &  \\
bb &\cellcolor{blue!25} 2     &\cellcolor{blue!25} 1     & \cellcolor{blue!25}1     &\cellcolor{blue!25} 1     & \cellcolor{blue!25}1     &       & \cellcolor{blue!25}1     &       & 3     &  \\
c &       &       &       &       &       & 3     &       &       &       & 3 \\
d &       &       &       &       &       &       & 3     & 3     &       &  \\
   f &       & 3     &       & 3     &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
gs & 3     &       & 4     &       & 3     &       &       &       &       & 5 \\
h &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &     \cellcolor{blue!25}2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
  \label{tab:smth}%
\end{table}%
\begin{center}
\vspace{-8mm}
\hspace{8mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{14cm}    % adjusting at the top
% do not draw the footnoterule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
\footnotetext[0] \noindent {{\footnotesize NOTES: dhfdfhdfhdd df sdhfjhsdf jkdfh     ksdjfh kdjfh djksfhjkdsk dsfh kjdfh. \\ 
}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have to manually change `vspace`, `hspace` and `minipage` length.

My question is this: is it possible to automate this procedure?

P.S. By the way, can I have the color in the first column only for the interior part of the table (aka after midrules)?

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if your example was a small document that demonstrated the problem. \footnote should work in longtable (mostly:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I changed it a little bit so it can be compiled and see the result.

Comment: thatnks why are you using `\footnotetext[0] \noindent`  ?`\footnotetext` is supposed to take the text of the footnote as argument but you are just passing it `\noindent` ???

Comment: You have no `\footnote` or `\footnotemark` commands in the example, and the `\footnotetext` command has no text supplied,so it is hard to guess the intended use really.

Comment: `As you can see, I have to manually change vspace, hspace and minipage length.`  The example has no vspace or hspace

Comment: Incidentally, instead of featuring `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}` in the preamble, you should have `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. See p. 9 of the user guide of the `xcolor` package. Separately, do you have a reason for specifying `utf8x` instead of `utf8` as the option when loading the `inputenc` package?

Comment: @Mico If I do that with tables I get an error, because of `threeparttables`. No, I have no specific reason for the use of `utf8x` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. But is just putting the `minipage` inside the `table` environment an option for you? I also used `\addlinespace` from `booktabs` to space the notes away from the `\bottomrule` slightly.

Comment: @PaulGessler I just want to have notes on a table. Some environments do not accept `footnotetable` if I am right. I wrote this thread because I want to learn the easiest possible way to have notes for my tables. If you know a better way---which I obviously don't---please give some advice.